# Zoom image effect plugin in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, zooming

Looking for a jquery plugin or some jquery script that would do something like this:

If you roll the mouse over the main image, you can see the zooming of the image etc.

Anywhere I could find something that does similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is famous [jQZoom plugin](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/) for that. [See the demos here](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo1).

**Update:**

See:

- [AnythingZoomer](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/image.php)
- [15+ jQuery Plugins to Create Stunning Image Zoom Effects](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/02/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-stunning-image-zoom-effects.html)

Comment: Thanks for this - any others that may be covered by a MIT licence? The licence on this doesnt permit me using it in my project.